# JS: 'this' context keeps showing as undefined when within promise chains

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having an issue accessing `this` context inside of a `then()` promise chain.  I am getting `undefined` when I try to see the value of `this` after the debugger stops inside the `then()`.
I searched for previous questions about this and based off the answers, I tried to create a variable `foo` outside of the scope that was equal to `this` but that also comes back as undefined when I try to see the value of it when the debugger stops the code.

```
    updateQuantity: function(e,item) {
            if (e === null || e === "") {
                return
            }
            let originalQuantity = item.original_quantity;
            let updatedQuantity  = parseFloat(e)

            var foo = this;

            // can access other functions here, ex: this.updateName();

            axios.post('/api/inventory/' + item.inventory_id + '/update-quantity', {
                original_quantity: item.original_quantity,
                quantity: updatedQuantity
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data && response.data.status == "success") {
                    this.showFlashMsg(response.data.message, true)
                    debugger
                } else if (response.data && response.data.status == "error") {
                    debugger
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        },
```

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal - did you read the code at all

Comment: yea that's what I expected but it's showing as `undefined` .  And `foo`, which I'd expect to give me the scope outside of the function is coming back as undefined too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were close.

TLDR;
At least when using Typescript or newer EcmaScript (JS) versions, using a lambda function (`=>`) will bind `this` to the correct object, hence Saurabh Agrawal's comment.

When using an old variant of JS/EcmaScript, you have to get a reference to the `this` you want to pass into your chained methods, and then use that instead of `this`. If I recall, this is what Typescript or other transpilers use when targeting an older version, as well.

Using your code (untested), this would like like:

```
updateQuantity: function(e,item) {
            if (e === null || e === "") {
                return
            }
            let originalQuantity = item.original_quantity;
            let updatedQuantity  = parseFloat(e)

            // ADDED COMMENT -- looks like you already had a reference, just weren't using it
            var foo = this;

            // can access other functions here, ex: this.updateName();

            axios.post('/api/inventory/' + item.inventory_id + '/update-quantity', {
                original_quantity: item.original_quantity,
                quantity: updatedQuantity
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data && response.data.status == "success") {
                    // EDIT -- use your variable reference to `this`
                    foo.showFlashMsg(response.data.message, true)
                    debugger
                } else if (response.data && response.data.status == "error") {
                    debugger
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        },
```

Comment: strange, that works.  Why would it be when running `console.log(foo)` above the `debugger` statements would it show `undefined`  ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Make sure you have `log` values displaying in the dev tools, though. Sometimes those get filtered out.

Comment: Oh, because `console.log` doesn't return a value, so it outputs `undefined` in the window. However, if you have `verbose` selected in the chrome console filters, you should see both your console output _and_ `undefined`